# Waiting time of second draw

Tags: probability, random-variables

We are given $2$ white balls and $n-2$ black balls in a urn, with $n \geq 3$. We draw each ball without replacement and we denote by $X$ the random variable which assign the number of the draw giving the first white ball. Denote by $Y$ the random variable which assigne the number of the draw giving the second white ball.

Is there an easy way to see that $X$ and $n+1-Y$ have the same law?

Comment: Yes. Choose a random pair S of {1,2,...,n} uniformly randomly, then X is the smallest element of the pair min(S) and Y is its largest element max(S). Now, send S to n+1-S, the distribution of the pair stays the same (again uniform on the set of pairs) but now min(n+1-S)=n+1-max(S) hence X=n+1-Y in distribution (and more is true, as the construction shows, for example (X,Y)=(n+1-Y,n+1-X) in distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say the same as @Did with other words (don't know why he didn't make his comment answer), imagine you decide that you will, whatever happens, always draw all the balls and put them in a line, from left to right. Then $X$ is the number of the first white ball when counting from the left, while $n+1-Y$ is the number of the first white ball you hit when counting from the right. Since every position is just as likely to have a white ball in it, counting from the right and from the left gives the same result.